# FileDialog not working in JApplet

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, japplet

I am converting an application from standalone (JFrame) to an Applet (JApplet). I have changed the parameter in the FileDialog constructor from parent frame to getContentPane and this is not working fine. I got the class Cast exception saying cannot cast Jpanel to Frame.

Please find the SSCCE. please help me to figure this issue.

```
public class SampleApplet extends JApplet{

protected JButton countryButton = new JButton("Select");

public synchronized void init()
{
    this.setBounds(new Rectangle(350,350));
    this.add(countryButton);


    countryButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            getCountries();
            getCountries();             
        }

    });
}

protected void getCountries() {
    FileDialog fileDialog_ImageIn = new FileDialog((Frame) getContentPane() ,"Select a GIF file", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fileDialog_ImageIn.setVisible(true);
    if (fileDialog_ImageIn.getFile() == null) 
        return;
    else
        System.out.println(fileDialog_ImageIn.getDirectory() + fileDialog_ImageIn.getFile());
}
```

}

Comment: Applets are oudated and I think you should look at Java Web start

Comment: If you want to have a file dialog with Swing, I would take a look at [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html). Mixing Swing and AWT components can lead to buggy behavior.

Comment: Thanks Jeffery for reminding this. I have did the same mistake earlier. I will Try JfileChooser

Comment: @Jeffrey  Generally good advice, but note this is one of the few (corner case) situations where the typical 'odd rendering' caused by mixing Swing with AWT does not manifest. ;)

Comment: I tried with JFilechooser and its working fine Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> I am converting an application from standalone (JFrame) to an Applet (JApplet).

Don't do that!  Instead, launch the frame from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It will provide a better user experience, and will be simpler to develop and deploy.

### BTW

1. The Swing based `JFileChooser` is better (more configurable etc.) than the AWT based `FileDialog`.
2. Either an applet or a frame launched using JWS needs to be trusted in order to use either of those classes.  If the app. is launched using JWS, the JNLP API provides a way to access the file-system that even works for fully sand-boxed code, though it would take some changes, since it uses a mechanism other than either of the 2 components I mentioned above in point 1.  Here is a small [demo. of the JNLP file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).  Try the sand-boxed version, see if it might work for your use-case.  The link to the code is to the right of the launch buttons.

Comment: Which 'this' - JWS?  Are you going to extend that to using the JNLP API to open the file?  (Note that if you are running the code from an IDE, it will generally not have a security sand-box - it will have a sand-box once the code is embedded in a web-page or launched using JWS.)